# Open MPI compilation error

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I am trying to compile open MPI (release 1.5.4) from the source code on a Macbook Pro (OS X Lion) with Xcode 4.1 installed. I configure the openmpi with the following options;

```
../configure CFLAGS=-m64 CXXFLAGS=-m64 FFLAGS=-m64 FCFLAGS=-m64 --with-wrapper-cflags=-m64 --with-wrapper-cxxflags=-m64
```

in a new/clean directory. When I try `make` it gives me the following error;

```
    Making all in otfprofile
  CXX    otfprofile-otfprofile.o
  CXX    otfprofile-CSVParse.o
  CXX    otfprofile-DataStructure.o
  CXX    otfprofile-Handler.o
  CXX    otfprofile-Prodtex.o
  CXX    otfprofile-Summary.o
  CXXLD  otfprofile
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___builtin_expect", referenced from:
      _main.omp_fn.0 in otfprofile-otfprofile.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[9]: *** [otfprofile] Error 1
make[8]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[7]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[6]: *** [all] Error 2
make[5]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I have `gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)`, gfortran `GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)`
I heard that I can use MacPorts for an easy installation but I want to compile it myself from the source. Can someone suggest me if I need to set some extra flags or what is causing this error? Please let me know if you need any further information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`__builtin_expect` is a gcc extension. I'd guess the clang/LLVM move from Apple doesn't support that but thinks it's gcc still.

There's a macro in OpenMPI which is set conditionally, but most likely incorrectly here. Since `__builtin_expect` is just an optimisation to hint about branch prediction you can probably fix the build by forcing the macro `OMPI_CXX_HAVE_BUILTIN_EXPECT` to be undefined during build.

Comment: Dear awoodland, thanks for your reply. Could you let me know if I have to do that in the 'prefetch.h' or somewhere else?

Comment: @UCU110 I think I'd put `#undef OMPI_CXX_HAVE_BUILTIN_EXPECT` on the line before `#if OMPI_CXX_HAVE_BUILTIN_EXPECT` in prefetch.h, but I'm not overly familiar with the internals of OpenMPI.

Comment: Dear awoodland, thanks a lot for your time but it did not work.

Comment: it's definitely something like that you want to do to solve it - you don't lose anything important by getting rid of all the uses of `__builtin_expect`.

Comment: Dear awoodland, '--disable-vt' in the "configure" has done the job.